# xml read is ok but cant write back

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

I  have xml document contains data:

```
<patients>
 <patient>
    <firstname>Patience_name_1</firstname>
    <lastname>Patience_surname_1</lastname>
    <age>20</age>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <exams>
      <exam>
      <examname>1th Exam of Patient 1</examname>
        <id>1</id>
        <date>2/29/2016 12:18:44</date>
        <comment>**1th Exam completed for patience1</comment>
      </exam>
    </exams>
  </patient>
  <patient>
    <firstname>Patience_name_2</firstname>
    <lastname>Patience_surname_2</lastname>...
```

I read the file and update for exp. firstname and write it with new file name("editedList.xml").

```
public List<patient> ReadXML()
    {
        List<patient> overview = new List<patient>();
        try
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer reader =
                    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(patients));
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("data.xml");
            var data = (patients)reader.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            overview = data.patients_list.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return overview;
    }
    public void WriteXML(string patientName)
    {
        List <patient> patients = this.ReadXML();
        patients.Where(w => w.name == patientName).Select(s =>
        {
            s.name = DataKeeper.selectedPatient.name.ToString();
            s.surname = DataKeeper.selectedPatient.surname.ToString();
            s.gender= DataKeeper.selectedPatient.gender.ToString();
            return s;
        } ).ToList();
        try
        {
            patients p = new patients();
            p.patients_list = patients;
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer writer =
                    new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(patients));
            var wfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"editedList.xml");
            writer.Serialize(wfile, patients);//Throw exception
            wfile.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
    }
```

In read there is no problem, after I edit a field I want to write it but the line show above throw an exception with "There was an error generating the XML document." message.

**EDITED**
StackTrace:

```
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o)
   at WpfApplication1.DataReader.WriteXML(String patientName) in C:\Users\yener.yilmaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WpfApplication1\WpfApplication1\DataReader.cs:line 49
```

Comment: Can you post the ex.StackTrace?  An XML file cannot have an array at the root level.  Xml can have only a single tag at the root.  I think your code will produce multiple tags at root level since the root is an array.  You have to add a root tag around the array for code to work.

Comment: Hello, post edited

Comment: Can't help without full StackTrace including Inner Exception.  Please don't edit the StackTrace.  All the info is needed.